# Can't set user.is_active and user.is_admin to True

Tags: python, django, superuser

I need to use email for authentication instead of user but when ever I create super user it doesn't set the is_active and is_admin to True which are False by default!

models.py

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User must have an email')
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("User must have a password")
        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            username = username,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(email, username, password)
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user
    

class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    objects = CustomUserManager
```

setting

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "account.User"
```

SQL table for users

```
id  ...   is_active is_staff    is_admin    is_superuser
1   ...       0        1           0            1
2   ...       0        1           0            1
3   ...       0        1           0            1
4   ...       0        1           0            1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still using the *old* manager (the `_base_manager`), you should set the new manager by *creating* a manager object:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    # …

    objects = CustomUserManager()  # 🖘 use parenthesis
```

This will then also set `User._default_manager` to this `CustomUserManager` object, which is used by the `createsuperuser` command. Indeed, in the [source code <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.1/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py#L233-L235), we see:

> ```
> self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(
>     **user_data
> )
> ```